# Confused: declined - flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, closed-questions, moderation

So, I find a question that I answered has been closed as not constructive (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17006836/npm-bundle-for-java). I'm happy that it's closed, because it's actually a duplicate, but I'm confused as to why the question has actually been closed as non-constructive -- I think it's constructive, and the duplicate wasn't closed, and I'm a little worried that closing things for the wrong reason is unhelpful to readers, so I hop onto meta and do some research.

I don't want to duplicate the research results here, because it'll take too long and who can be bothered, right? But, the result was that if something is closed for the wrong reason, and you feel strongly about it, you should flag it to the moderators, explaining in detail what the problem is.

So I did. I spent my valuable time trying to contribute to SO -- as I often do -- trying to improve something, not for myself, but altruistically for other users.

And, in response, I get told that I'm doing it wrong.

Ok, that's a bit rude, when I've spent time trying to help, but I'm not that thin skinned so I'll not worry too much about that, and besides I'm pretty sure it wasn't personal.

More importantly, it isn't the response I expected -- I expected helpful or not-helpful response. The response I got confused me, because I was pretty sure I was using the flag system right -- as I have done hundreds and hundreds of times before (mostly helpfully I'll add).

My question then is simply this: why did I get this particular response?

Comment: Are you sure the dupe shouldn't be closed too?

Comment: Deleted my answer as I completely missed the point of the question and wasn't helping at all.

Comment: And I got a downvote for asking for guidance. I love SO, but MSO seems horribly hostile.

Comment: Don't take offense to it.  It likely means someone disagrees with your premise.  Or someone lost their keys.  You don't lose rep here so it shouldn't be any skin off of your back.

Comment: @Makoto: No, but they gained a negative mark on their MSO profile. I'd say that's a bigger slap in the face than demerit rep points - until you *do* understand how inconsequential downvotes on meta are supposed to be anyway.

Comment: Not too worried about my rep -- a couple of minuses here and there aren't important. More worried about asking for guidance in future though -- may not do so as I'm not left feeling terribly welcome, and future readers may also be put off asking similar questions. Though, Ben Voigt's answer below is excellent and does answer my question.

Comment: That was closed before we had a specific close reason for questions asking for links/libraries/recommendations.  There's no need for mods to sift through the tens of thousands of questions closed for obsolete reason X to be closed for new reason Y, obviously.  There really isn't a need for a mod to do this for this question, either.  Don't forget--SO gets hundreds of flags a day, and only has a small force of volunteers to field them. Is there *really* a need to throw this on top of the pile?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That decline reason means that the moderator doesn't see anything that couldn't have been dealt with by the community (usually, either 2k rep users or 10k users).

In the general case when you find a duplicate after the question is closed, you can deal with it yourself just by leaving a comment containing a link to the related question.  This causes a link also to appear in the "Linked" questions list at the right-hand side of the question.

In this particular case, you left an answer before the question got closed.  That's an even better place to add the link.

Answer (score 5):

There's two parts to this.  Let's start with the moderator flag.

> [I]f something is closed for the wrong reason, and you feel strongly about it, you should flag it to the moderators, explaining in detail what the problem is.

The community at large can vote to reopen questions that it feels should be reopened, and in general, where and when the community can, it *should*.  In this scenario, this is something that is accomplishable by yourself and four others, so a moderator shouldn't need to intervene.

Creating a Meta post and letting others weigh in would have been a more appropriate action.  You may incur downvotes for it, but again, those signify more disagreement than incorrectness.

If the question were otherwise unactionable by yourself, you would want to seek moderator help for it.  This is for things like, you can't edit the question because it's locked for a reason that *isn't* historical.  Or, you're suspicious of the OP's intent with the question as it seems like a product placement and astroturfing campaign on SO.

Second, I looked at the questions a bit closer, and they don't feel like duplicates.  There is an objective answer out there, which would be useful for someone moving to Java from a JavaScript/Ruby/Python sort of background, so I don't feel that it's off topic either.  The main issue with the answer that you've linked is that it's mostly devolved into dependency management tool listings, whereas a good answer would try to encapsulate what the actual standard for dependency management is, as well as give a listing of the most common tools out there.