# Add details about when to use custom flag

Tags: discussion, feature-request, flags, help-center

I've noticed that many posts asking about why this or that custom flag ("needs ♦ moderator attention") was declined are confused about the accompanying comment

> declined - flags should only be used to make moderators aware of
>   content that requires their intervention

Some examples from a quick search on MetaSO for "requires intervention":

- [What is the appropriate action to take when something is seemingly wrongfully closed?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354916/what-is-the-appropriate-action-to-take-when-something-is-seemingly-wrongfully-cl)
- [Confused: declined - flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306619/confused-declined-flags-should-only-be-used-to-make-moderators-aware-of-conte)
- [Off-topic flag declined because of strange reason](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261871/off-topic-flag-declined-because-of-strange-reason)
- [Why was my flag rejected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280042/why-was-my-flag-rejected)

The confusion seems to stem partially from what it is possible for the community to handle without moderator intervention, and what special tools moderators have that the community does not.

The current message for the custom flag says "A problem not listed above that requires action by a moderator. *Be specific and detailed*"

This should in theory cover any other flag reasons (although some users persist in using this when they could have used another flag), but it does not cover actions that the community can take by voting, such as opening, closing, and deleting questions. Often, users without these privileges, do not realize that the community is largely responsible for these tasks, not moderators.

There is a good [summary of moderator privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/site-moderators) on the help pages, and it could easily be rephrased to focus on when a moderator flag is recommended.

For example,

> Moderators also have some special abilities necessary to handle
>   rare exceptional conditions that are not handled by other flags:
>
> - Flag a moderator to lock a post. Locked posts cannot be voted on or changed in any way. Common reasons to lock posts include edit wars, extended bickering in the comments or being under discussion on Meta. See [Locked Posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/locked-posts) for more information.
> - Flag a moderator if you suspect systematic abuse by a user. Moderators can place users in timed suspension, and delete users if necessary.
> - Flag a moderator for large-scale maintenance actions such as merging questions and tags, tag synonym approvals, and so forth.

In addition, it might be good to have a summary somewhere of actions that do *not* require moderator intervention.

Something like,

> Please, do not flag a moderator for actions that are handled by
>   standard flags or for
>
> - Reopening posts
> - Closing posts
> - Deleting posts
>
> These actions are more properly handled by community voting.
>
> If you believe your question was unjustly closed, please 
>   [ask a question about it on Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?tags=discussion+specific-question+vote-to-reopen), and have
>   a very strong argument as to why the post should be reopened at all.

(I borrowed the last paragraph from this excellent answer:
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/354918/3303546)

I would put this guidance in the help center near [the other flag usage guidance](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) and add a link to it in the custom flag message.

I know that this will not help prevent all confusion about custom flags, because not everyone reads the help center, but having usage guidelines would give us something to point to, and help interested parties (me included) be better.

Comment: The problem is, it is basically impossible to create an exhaustive list of what you would use a custom moderator flag for, and I would prefer that we don't even try, because it might discourage people from using it in cases where a flag would be appropriate. So yeah, making a list of things that it should *not* be used for is probably okay. Or just learning from your "declined" flags would be cool, too...

Comment: @Don'tPanic That's why I suggest just linking to the information. That way people who want to educate themselves can, and don't have to wade through pages of meta posts. While people who want to read the minimum can stick to the existing message.

Comment: @CodyGray I agree that an exhaustive list is not possible, but I think a sketch might still be useful, especially for users unfamiliar with the site. I think it could be written in a way that makes it clear that other circumstances might also warrant a diamond moderator flag.

Comment: @Cecilia I deleted my previous comment after rereading your question. Somehow I missed that bit the first time through. Too many words for me, I guess. ;)

Comment: Why are users so overly concerned about a couple of declined flags?

Comment: Probably because the system swats it in their faces, @Shadow. "Several of your flags have recently been declined; check up on them you moron before raising another worthless flag" (I'm paraphrasing a bit). The intent is good, but it comes across badly. I recall that vividly from before I was elected moderator.

Comment: @CodyGray I do not like it either if a mod declines my flag (or if my answer gets downvoted, etc), but they are not the end of the world. If there is no flag ban, then why bother? Learn from it and move on. If you really do not get why a specific flag was declined, then you can always ask here.

Comment: I would be perfectly okay with the flag warning dialog if it didn't linger for a week at a time. "Hey, a mod declined three of your flags five days ago. You suck."

Comment: @CodyGray time to put that PTSD to good use and Approve All The Things ;)

Comment: Maybe mention chat.  Discovering the [SOCVR chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) was for me an eye-opener which significantly reduced stress and frustration over my flags seemingly getting ignored or lost. When you have a fallback route to the user community (or should I say *a* user community), the threshold to contact a moderator in uncertain cases is raised significantly.

Comment: (Before that, I randomly scoured chat looking for a room where I could contact a "moderator on call" on several occasions, but never found one. I guess there isn't formally any place to contact moderators to discuss whether a flag is warranted.)

Comment: I think this whole issue is confused by the fact that there's literally an option for "should be closed" when flagging if you don't have the close vote privilege (also that you can't (seem to) provide a custom explanation for why it should be closed there). Why users think custom flags and "should be closed" flags are fundamentally different?

Comment: Add "migration to other sites".